# Import Tax - "made in China" versus "made in Taiwan"

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, customs-law

Is there any reason for tax purposes a company would stamp made in Taiwan, when the products are actually made in China?

Do you pay less tax or VAT when you import them in to the UK?

They might do it because it sounds better to the consumer, but I don't think that would be the only reason.

Comment: What does "China" mean? Maybe the issue is related to the fact that Taiwan "official name" is Republic of China and formally is still fighting the People's Republic of China (Mainland China) over control of all of China. Maybe someone meant "Republic of China" but it was understood as "China" all along? Could you clarify the details?

Comment: Given that the UK officially does not recognise the existence of the ROC (Taiwan), wouldn't anything marked "Made in Taiwan" simply be treated as if it were marked "Made in China"?

Comment: @SJuan76 the "official" status of Taiwan is that it is a province of China.

Answer (score 4):

In term of international trade practice , "Taiwan" is technically the "Separate Customs Territory of Taiwan, Penghu, Kinmen and Matsu (Chinese Taipei)" based on the entry agreement of World Trade Organization (WTO) . It's similar to "Hong Kong" even that's a little different in legal term and tax practice.